# How can I $push an item in two different fields, depending on the condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to receive the user location and store it in the database. Also, the user can choose if he wants to save all his previous locations or not.
So I have created a boolean variable historicEnable: true/false.
So when the historicEnable is true, I want to push to `historicLocation[]` array in the UserSchema and if it is false, I want just to update `currentLocation[]` array in the UserSchema.

conntrollers/auth.js

```
exports.addLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const {phone, location, status, historicEnable} = req.body;
  let theLocation;
  
  if (historicEnable== true){
    theLocation = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { phone },
      { $push:{ locationHistoric: location, statusHistoric: status }},
      { new: true }
    )
  } else if(historicEnable== false){
    theLocation = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { phone },
      { location, status },
      { new: true }
    )
  }

  res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "A location as been created",
      data: theLocation,
      locationHistory: locationHistory
  })
})
```

models/User.js

```
...
  currentLocation: [
    {
      location: {
        latitude: {type:Number},
        longitude: {type:Number},
      },

      status: {
        type: String
      },
    
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      }
    }
  ],

  historicLocation: [
    {
      locationHistoric: {
        latitude: {type:Number},
        longitude: {type:Number},
      },

      statusHistoric: {
        type: String
      },
    
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      }
    }
  ]
```

Also, not sure how to make the request body so the function works.

req.body

```
{
  "phone": "+1234",
  "historicEnable": true,
  "loications": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 25,
        "longitude": 35
      },
      "status": "safe"
    }
  ]
}
```

To sum up, if historicEnable is true, the data will be pushed in historicLocation, and if it false, to update the currentLocation.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an update with an aggregation pipeline. If the `historicEnable` is known only on db level:

```
db.collection.update(
  {phone: "+1234"},
  [
    {$addFields: {
      location: [{location: {latitude: 25, longitude: 35}, status: "safe"}]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      historicLocation: {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: ["$historicEnable", true]},
          {$concatArrays: ["$historicLocation", "$location"]},
          "$historicLocation"
        ]
      },
      currentLocation: {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: ["$currentLocation", false]},
          {$concatArrays: ["$currentLocation", "$location"]},
          "$currentLocation"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "location"
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/guJKqbf4z_0)

If `historicEnable` is known from the input, you can do something like:

```
exports.addLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const phone = req.body.phone
  const historicEnable= req.body.historicEnable
  const locObj = req.body.location.locationHistoric[0];
  locObj.createdAt = req.body.createdAt
  const updateQuery = historicEnable ? { $push:{ locationHistoric: locObj}} : { $push:{ currentLocation: locObj}};


  const theLocation = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { phone },
      updateQuery,
      { new: true }
    )
  

  res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "A location as been created",
      data: theLocation,
      locationHistory: locationHistory
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do it mongoose at my function

Comment: Please provide sample data: a db document, request value and expected results

Comment: ```{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "A location as been created",
  "data": {
    "_id": "629dd396b72b62e18e93a0d2",
    "phone": "+1234",
    "createdAt": "2022-06-06T10:14:46.816Z",
    "currentLocation": [],
    "historicLocation": [],
    "__v": 0,
    "birthdate": "2000-12-12",
    "fullName": "MARIO",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  "historicEnable": true
}```

Comment: This is the response: when the historicEnable is true, the request body should be pushed in the current location(the idea is to store more then one location, as a history), and if its false, just to update the currentLocation. historicEnable is not known on db, its just a variable that I declare in the req.body to make the conditions work(it will come from front end)

Comment: I understand very well your logic, and I think it will work, but I got stuck in the request.body I have to make so the function returns me the right response. req.body:```{
  "phone": "+1234",
  "historicEnable": true,
  "locationHistoric": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 25,
        "longitude": 35
      },
      "status": "safe"
    }
  ]
}``` So if I console.log-it, it will return undefined. Is it a mistake I have to correct it

Comment: If the req.body is undefined then it is outside of the context of this question. You should ask another question regarding it, with the relevant data

Comment: it was a mistake on my side, the right question is the array in what key name should it be. Thank you! currentLocation or historicLocation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245359/discussion-between-mier23-and-nimrod-serok).